# Странное поведение в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
pars = []
my_count = 0.0
while my_count <= 10:
    pars.append(my_count)
    my_count += 0.1
    my_count = int(my_count*100) / 100
print(pars)
```

out:

> [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,
>   1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.09, 4.18, 4.27, 4.36, 4.46, 4.55, 4.64, 4.73, 4.83, 4.93, 5.02, 5.11, 5.21, 5.31, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.69, 5.79, 5.89, 5.98, 6.08, 6.18, 6.27, 6.36, 6.46, 6.56, 6.65, 6.75, 6.85, 6.94, 7.04, 7.14, 7.23, 7.33, 7.43, 7.52, 7.61, 7.71, 7.81, 7.9, 8.0, 8.1, 8.19, 8.28, 8.37, 8.46, 8.56, 8.66, 8.76, 8.86, 8.95, 9.04, 9.13, 9.23, 9.33, 9.43, 9.52, 9.61, 9.7, 9.79, 9.88, 9.98]

Почему все ломается и почему это происходит каждый раз на 4?

Comment: А какой ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вещественные числа имеют не точное представление, попробуйте приводить к строке с указанием точности, чтобы получить ожидаемые числа:

```
pars = []
my_count = 0.0
while my_count <= 10:
    pars.append(my_count)
    my_count += 0.1

print(['{:.1f}'.format(num) for num in pars])
```

---

Или сразу в цикле:

```
pars = []
my_count = 0.0
while my_count <= 10:
    pars.append('{:.1f}'.format(my_count))
    my_count += 0.1

print(pars)
```

Результат:

> ['0.0', '0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5', '0.6', '0.7', '0.8', '0.9',
> '1.0', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '1.5', '1.6', '1.7', '1.8', '1.9',
> '2.0', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '2.4', '2.5', '2.6', '2.7', '2.8', '2.9',
> '3.0', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '3.4', '3.5', '3.6', '3.7', '3.8', '3.9',
> '4.0', '4.1', '4.2', '4.3', '4.4', '4.5', '4.6', '4.7', '4.8', '4.9',
> '5.0', '5.1', '5.2', '5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6', '5.7', '5.8', '5.9',
> '6.0', '6.1', '6.2', '6.3', '6.4', '6.5', '6.6', '6.7', '6.8', '6.9',
> '7.0', '7.1', '7.2', '7.3', '7.4', '7.5', '7.6', '7.7', '7.8', '7.9',
> '8.0', '8.1', '8.2', '8.3', '8.4', '8.5', '8.6', '8.7', '8.8', '8.9',
> '9.0', '9.1', '9.2', '9.3', '9.4', '9.5', '9.6', '9.7', '9.8', '9.9',
> '10.0']

---

**PS.** небольшой пример этой особенности вещественных чисел:

```
print(0.3)               # 0.3
print(0.2 + 0.1)         # 0.30000000000000004
print(0.3 == 0.2 + 0.1)  # False
```

А чтобы сравнить два числа, нужно сделать вычитание по модулю и результат сравнить с маленькой величиной (эпсилон):

```
def is_equal(a, b, eps=0.0000001):
    return abs(a - b) < eps

print(is_equal(0.3, 0.2 + 0.1))  # True
print(is_equal(0.3, 0.3))        # True
print(is_equal(0.3, 0.4))        # False
```

Comment: почему python сходит с ума именно на четверке?)

Comment: Я так и не понял про какую четверку вы писали, тыкните пальцем

Comment: 4.0, 4.09 в списке, тыкнул

Comment: до 4.0 шаг 0.1 как и должен быть, после 4 шаг становится 0.09. Запускал скрипт несколько раз, каждый раз шаг ломается именно на 4.0

Comment: Думаю, из-за погрешности, которая возникла при `my_count = int(my_count*100) / 100`. Добавьте в цикл `print(my_count, '{:.20f}'.format(my_count))`, чтобы увидеть насколько большая точность у тех чисел. Вообще, погрешность вещественных чисел накапливается при арифметических операциях с ними